# Process sticks to 1 CPU

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I am running an Ubuntu Server having 48 CPUs hosting 6 Docker containers with 8 CPU each. These containers run a script which spawn multiple child processes, in parallel (As it shows in pstree). All of these processes run on only 1 CPU, leaving the other 7 CPU of that container unused. Why all child processes are running on only that CPU, and not others? Is there a way I can fix it?

Comment: What leads you to believe they run on only one CPU?  Unless you have multi-threaded processes, each process can only run on one CPU, although multiple processes should be able to run on different CPUs.  Unless you have sufficient load, it will not be obvious that load is being distributed.

Comment: I see this in “nmon” only 1 CPU is being utilized 100% the rest are 0% utilized.

Comment: And yes the process is multi threaded

Comment: It seems that the contain thinks it has only one CPU or you are blocking on a resource.  However, if you where blocking on a resource, I would still expect the CPU load to be distributed.